# Counting several groups of variables within same attribute table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, summarizing

I have a building layer. Different types of buildings have different codes, and several types of buildings belong to the same group (not actual codes but as an example codes 100-149 are residential buildings, 150-199 are industrial, 200-224 are schools, 225-250 are shops etc etc).

What I'd like to do is to summarize how many buildings are in each group. I know I can get the count or frequency through the summarize tool, but that would give me individual numbers for types 100, 101, 102 etc. Surely there must be a way to group things first?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: You need to create a new field which is your group field and recode your numeric ID's into those building categories, then run it through the summary tool.

Comment: Or you can run stats if you do not want to modify the original data and then apply what @Hornbydd has suggested.

Comment: I went for @Hornbydd s solution. Definitely solved the issue easily! Thank you for your input!